# How to find number of assets inside a matrix block?

Tags: assets, matrix

I have a matrix block which has an asset field inside of it. I want to know how many assets are inside the block, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah you should be able to do something like

`{{ block.assetField|length }}`

Answer (score 1):

This is old but it looks like there was never an accepted answer. This seems to work for me.

```
{% set count = block.carouselImages.count() %}
```